# Pass data from server to client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have now;

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(){
 var test = 'test';
 console.log(test);
});
```

this will showed up on the server, but how do i get this variable at the client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better read the Socket.io [docs](http://socket.io/docs/). There are very good examples which you can use in a straightforward fashion.

The server code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event from client', function (data) {
    // This will print to the console of your server app.
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

The client code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    // This will print to the console of your browser.
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event from client', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Basically, you should call `emit()` to send data to the client. The `console.log()` is an internal function which will print the data to the console of your server app. It doesn't send any data to the client.